# Elastic relative data math - finding all things today

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone, date-math

I'm trying to do so fairly simple query with Elasticsearch, but I don't think I understand what I'm doing wrong, so I'm posting here for some pointers.

I have an elastic index where each document has a date like so:

```json
{
  // edited for brevity
  "releasedate": "2020-10-03T15:55:03+00:00",
}
```

and I am using django DRF to make queries like so, where I pass this value along `&releasedate__gt=now-3d/d`

Which ends up with an elastic range query like this.

```json
{
  
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "releasedate": {
              "gt": "now/d-3d"
            }
          }
        }
        ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    "_score"
  ]
}
```

If I want to see all "documents since yesterday", I think of it in terms of *all documents with `releasedate` greater than midnight yesterday*, I figured the key part of the query would need to be like so:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "releasedate": {
              "gt": "now/d-1d"
            }
          }
        }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

So I expect this would round the time now, to 00:00 today, then go back one day.

So if I ran this on 2020-10-04. I'd assume this would catch a document with the release date of  `2020-10-03T15:55:03+00:00`.

Here's my reasoning

Rounding down with `now/d` would take us to  `2020-10-04T00:00`.

And then going back one day with `-1d` would take us to `2020-10-03T00:00`.

This ought to include the document, but I'm not seeing it. I need to look back more than one day to find the documents, so I need to use `now/d-2d` to find matching documents.

Any idea why this might be? I'm unsure of how to see what `now/d-1d` evaluates in terms of a timezone aware object, to check -  that's what I might reach for, but I don't know *how* with Elastic.

FWIW, this is using Elastic 5.6. We'll be updating soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that once you round [**down** to the nearest day](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) (either with `now-2d/d` or `now/d-2d` -- as you did), the `gt` query's intervals will indeed be day-based.

In other words, `gt : 2020-10-03T00:00` is `>= 2020-10-0`*`4`*`T00:00`. So what you need instead of `gt` is **`gte`** and that'll work as `>=2020-10-03T00:00`.